# export 'datetime.date' to excel via xlwings

Tags: datetime, pandas, export-to-excel, xlwings

I have a pandas `dataframe` with a `datetime.date` column.

I try to export the `dataframe` to excel via `xlwings`.
I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'microsecond'
```

I am quite confident the error takes place in the translation between the `datetime.date` type column into the excel equivalent.

The obvious solution would be convert the column into `datetime` which should map to the excel timestamp (`16.02.2015  00:00:00` -> `42051`).

Are there alternatives to that? I find quite odd that there isn't a `Date` type in Excel. Are there workarounds? Add a dummy `time` of the day to the `date` just to convert the column into `datetime` for the sake of exporting it to excel is not the (type) safest solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug as logged [here](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/44) and admittedly it's a shame it hasn't been resolved yet.

However, in the case of a Pandas DataFrame, you can for now workaround the issue by converting the column into a Pandas datetime column:

```
df.DateColumn = pandas.to_datetime(df.DateColumn)
```

Comment: This should now have been resolved with xlwings v0.3.3